# I need a web service to open audio from the server and provide a uri that I can access from anywhere

Tags: web-services, service, streaming

I am not familiar with web services, what is the best technology/service to use or implement to to be hosted on a server to provide audio in a .mp3 uri 
example: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/64382000/mirror.mp3
I need to implement a service to do the same

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

RESTful Web Service should do the job. Use [this](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/webservices/library/ws-restful) as a starting point.

Answer (score 0):

In theory you should be able to use a web server (like Apache, nginx, your favorite web server) and just host the mp3's statically.